# how to use numpy to shorten tic-tac-toe check

Tags: python, numpy, tic-tac-toe, magic-square

how to use numpy to shorten my code where i check if you win or not

i need to find a way to use numpy to fit into my code because its very long and hard.
i check diag, horizontle and row but i need to find a way to shorten it with numpy

```
def checkHorizontle(board):
    global winner
    if board[0] == board[1] == board[2] and board[1] != "-":
        winner = board[0]
        return True
    elif board[3] == board[4] == board[5] and board[3] != "-":
        winner = board[3]
        return True
    elif board[6] == board[7] == board[8] and board[6] != "-":
        winner = board[6]
        return True

    
def checkRow(board):
    global winner
    if board[0] == board[3] == board[6] and board[0] != "-":
        winner = board[0]
        return True
    elif board[1] == board[4] == board[7] and board[1] != "-":
        winner = board[1]
        return True
    elif board[2] == board[5] == board[8] and board[2] != "-":
        winner = board[2]
        return True


def checkDiag(Board):
    global winner
    if board[0] == board[4] == board[8] and board[0] != "-":
        winner = board[0]
        return True
    elif board[2] == board[4] == board[6] and board[2] != "-":
        winner = board[2]
        return True
```

when i tried to find a sulution my mind just decided to quit. i know you could youe the magic square to find it and the numpy multiply fuction but i dont know how to

Comment: You don't need numpy to shorten this, only a for loop. Also, magic square is for grid of numbers, not strings/booleans

Comment: your `board` looks like a list of 9 elements, each a string.  A numpy array that is (3,3) shape  may make some checks more succinct, but with this small size and string values, checks won't be any faster. As a numpy exercise it may have some value, but practically it won't help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for numpy, you can use a simple loop:

```
WINNING_TRIPLETS = [ (0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), ...] # add all of them

for square1, square2, square3 in WINNING_TRIPLETS:
    if ...: # same logic as in your code, but only once with square1, square2, square3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a board of this kind and wanting to check if `X` won:

```
board = np.array([['X', 'O', np.nan],
                  ['O', 'X', np.nan],
                  ['X', 'X', 'X']])
```

You can use 4 tests for rows, columns, and diagonals:

```
# check if any row is won
(board == 'X').all(axis=1).any()

# check if any column is won
(board == 'X').all(axis=0).any()

# check diagonals
diag1 = np.diagonal(board)
diag2 = np.diagonal(np.fliplr(board))
(diag1 == 'X').all() or (diag2 == 'X').all()
```

Use in a test:

```
if ((board == 'X').all(axis=1).any() 
   or (board == 'X').all(axis=0).any()
   or (np.diagonal(board) == 'X').all()
   or (np.diagonal(np.fliplr(board)) == 'X').all()
   ):
    print('X won')
```

If you want to check if any player won:

```
# check if any row is won
(board[0] == board[1:]).all(0).any()

# check if any column is won
(board[:, [0]] == board[:, 1:]).all(1).any()

# check diagonals
diag1 = np.diagonal(board)
diag2 = np.diagonal(np.fliplr(board))
(diag1[0] == diag1[1:]).all() or (diag2[0] == diag2[1:]).all()
```

Comment: I assume the `np.nan` elements are actualy, string 'nan', and could be anything other than 'X' or 'O'

Comment: @hpaulj no they are actual NaNs, this doesn't really matter if you use the first approach, but for the second this enables `board[0] == board[1:]` to give `True` for `'X' == 'X'` but `False` for `NaN == NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

> its very long and hard. ... i need to find a way to shorten it with numpy

If getting it short is your goal, you don't necessarily need numpy. Another idea is to represent the board as a string of nine characters (each is either "X", "O" or "."), and use a regex to test for a win.

That regex could be:

```
(\w)(\1\1(...)*$|..\1..\1|...\1...\1|.\1.\1..$)
```

An example implementation:

```
import re

class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = "........."

    def play(self, i):
        self.board = self.board[:i] + self.player() + self.board[i+1:]

    def player(self):
        return "OX"[self.board.count(".") % 2]

    def isdraw(self):
        return "." not in self.board
    
    def iswon(self):
        return bool(re.search(r"(\w)(\1\1(...)*$|..\1..\1|...\1...\1|.\1.\1..$)", self.board))
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "\n".join(" ".join(self.board[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, 9, 3))

# demo
game = TicTacToe()
for move in 0, 4, 8, 2, 6, 3, 7:
    game.play(move)
print(game)
print("draw?", game.isdraw())
print("win?", game.iswon())
```